# how to pass csrf-token in first request

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework, angular7, csrf-token

my question is how cookies works, this question is arrived in my mind when i loaded my page for first time i got this

```
REQUEST HEADER
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: csrftoken=gsZxmbW4XUpE6YnaQhlrAx9JduyExVgzWEo4fXhcY4V3fbHWVtwf0msbDQDT5r43
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

when first request was sent it already had csrftoken in cookie

i tried same in incognito window than also i got same  result.
how can my browser already have cookie  without any communication to server

i am working on django with angular 7, problems is that i am sending my request from angular

```
 this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/',data,  {observe : "response", withCredentials: true } )}
```

but in response of that i am not getting any csrftoken in setcookie .

please help me ..... sorry for adding two problems in one question but both are indirectly connected to each other

Comment: with all request  i have to pass csrftoken so how can  a person will send request who visits my website for first time because new person will not have csrf-token.

Answer (score 1):

CSRF can only stop to PUT , POST and DELETE, It's always open with GET request, If you are able to send it through GET on very 1st time , then thats well and good .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

actually thing was that django was running on 127.0.0.1 and angular was running on localhost( any loop back address) and that's why for security(CORS) issue, browser(chrome) was not allowing me to neither send cookie in request nor set cookie in response . so i had two options one change same-site to none in browser or change my angular setting to render on 127.0.0.1.