How to get initial CSRF token from Django to Angular frontend?
I have a Angular and Django setup for a site and I've set up CSRF tokens and everything. However I don't know how to generate an initial token so that the user can log in. When they try to log in, the backend complains that there is no CSRF token in the request.
I tried sending an empty get request when the login page is loaded, but that doesn't seem to send back a token. I also tried adding the @ensure_csrf_cookie decorator but that doesn't work either.
I imagine there is some standard way of doing this?

is it a dupplicate of this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57143297/how-to-pass-csrf-token-in-first-request

I don't think so? At least I don't see my question answered there

I fixed it, I had to add { withCredentials: true } to the initial GET request, then the CSRF token is set.
